# How do I ensure that SymPy's 'solve' only finds the first (nearest 0) solution?

Tags: python-2.7, trigonometry, sympy, complex-numbers

I'm having trouble getting reasonable solving speed from [SymPy's](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) `solve`.

I can get correct results using the code below, but

- it takes far too long to get them

and

- I'm also getting too many results (I only need the first), which means
- I have to go through awkward access to get the first one, and
- even then the first one isn't quite right, and I need do some ugly massaging to get what I want.

Clearly there are some things I don't understand about the effective use of SymPy, especially limiting results to the just one, and making sure that one is really the first one I'd expect (here, in particular the one nearest 0).

How do I ensure that SymPy's `solve` only (and relatively quickly) finds the first (nearest 0) solution?

---

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol
import sympy

MODEL_PLANETS = ['Mercury', 'Venus', 'Mars', 'Jupiter', 'Saturn']
ra_obs = dict(zip(['Sun'] + MODEL_PLANETS,
                  [ra / 24 for ra in [18.73930, 20.11652, 16.04319, 13.81240, 11.61406, 16.65653]]))
rho = dict(zip(['Sun'] + MODEL_PLANETS,
               [0.0, 0.387, 0.723, 0.656168, 0.192197, 0.104833]))


def f(x, p):
    if p in ['Mercury', 'Venus']:
        return sympy.exp(2 * sympy.pi * sympy.I * ra_obs['Sun']) + rho[p] * sympy.exp(2 * sympy.pi * sympy.I * x)
    else:
        return rho[p] * sympy.exp(2 * sympy.pi * sympy.I * ra_obs['Sun']) + sympy.exp(2 * sympy.pi * sympy.I * x)


theta = Symbol('theta', nonnegative=False)


def get_solution(p):
    s = sympy.re((solve([sympy.re(f(theta, p)) - sympy.cos(2 * sympy.pi * ra_obs[p]),
                         sympy.im(f(theta, p)) - sympy.sin(2 * sympy.pi * ra_obs[p])], theta)[0])[theta])
    return (24 * (s if s > 0 else 1 - s)) % 24


for p in MODEL_PLANETS:
    print('{} = {}'.format(p, 24 - get_solution(p)))
```

Comment: Try solving the system of equations using symbolic parameters in place of the floating-point variables. If `solve` is able to find symbolic solution(s), all you would have to do is to replace the parameters of the solution with their corresponding floating point numbers, which should be much faster compared to having to re-solve the system each time you provide a different parameter value.

Comment: If you are only interested in a numeric solution, you may have better luck with a numeric solver like `sympy.nsolve`.